Which Adaptation of Scooby Doo Is This?
I have been checking out the Scooby Doo adaptations, and remember watching hour long Scooby Doo episodes on weekends. To my knowledge, they were a part of the What's New, Scooby Doo? series, due to their art work and style. However, these episodes were longer than the regular ones. 
To give you some examples that may better help you understand what I am talking about, a few of these special episodes are as follows: Aloha, Scooby-Doo!, Scooby-Doo and the Cyber Chase, Scooby-Doo! and the Goblin King, and Scooby-Doo! and the Samurai Sword. 
I am looking for which series or adaptations these episodes were from (ex. What's New Scooby Doo, Scooby Doo, Where are you? etc.)

I don't understand the question. The links you provide seem to answer it. Can you be more specific?

@DanielStowers Whoops.

@BamfTheNightAway I am looking for what adaptations/series (What's New Scooby Doo, Scooby Doo Where Are you etc.) the listed shows (and the others that are similar) are under.

Generally speaking, Scooby-Doo has had an extensive filmography, spanning  46 years, 12 on-going cartoon series, 14 TV movies, 4 Live Action Movies, 25 Direct to Home Release movies, and 6 crossover series, NOT including video games, comics, or shorts. Wikipedia and IMDb for a full listing.

Art styles typically covered:

The Direct to Home Release and TV movies were rarely connected with the cartoon series at the time. **The ones you list, Aloha, Scooby-Doo!, Scooby-Doo and the Cyber Chase, Scooby-Doo! and the Goblin King, and Scooby-Doo! and the Samurai Sword are all Direct to Home Release movies that span 2000-2010, with only Cyber Chase having no direct connection to a series. The other three are part of the What's New Scooby Doo era, being spin-off films also produced by Warner Bros.:

The series also produced seven spin-off films set in the same style and animation like the series with the same voice cast as before, which continued after the series ended in 2006, up until 2009. The films in order are: Scooby-Doo! and the Loch Ness Monster (2004)
  Aloha, Scooby-Doo! (2005)
  Scooby-Doo! in Where's My Mummy? (2005)
  Scooby-Doo! Pirates Ahoy! (2006)
  Chill Out, Scooby-Doo! (2007)
  Scooby-Doo! and the Goblin King (2008)
  Scooby-Doo! and the Samurai Sword (2009)


I'd beg to differ that the art style for the 2000-2006 seems like the What's New series, and that the newer movies (2014) inherits the Mystery Incorporated however. Never knew they were standalone.

@Jake you are right, there is some connection. Spin off films developed by WB. Updated.
